# reaper.conf configuraton of reaper generate fault

Tags: 12.04, configuration

```
################################
host mine.pool-x.eu
port 9000
user USER.WORKER
pass PASSWORD
protocol litecoin


kernel reaper.cl
threads_per_gpu 1
aggression 13
worksize 256
save_binaries yes
cpu_mining_threads 0
platform 0
enable_graceful_shutdown no
long_polling no

kernel reaper.cl
threads_per_gpu 2
aggression 13
worksize 128
save_binaries yes
cpu_mining_threads 0
platform 0
enable_graceful_shutdown no
long_polling no

###############################################
```

OUTPUT:

```
2013-12-09 16:08:25 Error 52 getting work. See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html for error code explanations.
2013-12-09 16:08:25 Couldn't connect to server. Trying again in a few seconds...
```

Why this configuration is generate this fault? I use ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: "See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html for error code explanations" So why not tell us what an error 52 is? "CURLE_GOT_NOTHING (52)

Nothing was returned from the server, and under the circumstances, getting nothing is considered an error. " Is it this one? I would start by checking if the server runs and if the hostname is correct.

Comment: Host and worker exists. I know it because I've got any problem with this configuration using another application (minerd). On the other pools it is the same problem. I suppose the problem is in the version of curl package. But I realy don't know what should I do to run this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by running:

```
sudo apt-get install make automake build-essential libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Let me know if it helped.